# How to chain Functional components in React and Typescript (in a dot notation style)? E.g. <Parent.Child>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I have created a Template component in React and TypeScript where you could use each section within the Template to render different contents in. For example;

```
<Template>
    <Template.Main>
        This is the main sub-section within Default template.
    </Template.Main>
    <Template.Footer>
        This is the footer sub-section.
    </Template.Footer>
</Template>
```

Everything works and renders fine without any error on the console, however there is this TypeScript error "**Property Footer does not exist on type FC**", but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Somehow TypeScript does not like how I have chained different sections to the Template component, so I would appreciate if anybody could help me with this.

This is the TEMPLATES.REGIONS constant.

[image: This is the TEMPLATES.REGIONS constants]

This is the **< Template />** component itself.

[image]

This is how is rendered out.

[image]

This is how the < Template /> component is used in the main index file.

[image]

I have put a demo together in CodeSandbox, but for some reason it doesn't outputs any error over there and it only happens locally!

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-n1qyv

Thank in advance.

Comment: In your codesandbox, change `App.js` to `App.tsx`

Comment: You don't have any code which tells Typescript that you using Dot.Notation, using `Object.values` as you did, happens in run time, Typescript analyses styles at compile time. See duplicate.

Comment: Thank you, just edited the App ext to .tsx and yes I can now see the error over on CodeSandbox too.